# When will we have 2013 Moderator Elections?

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

Hello community of webmasters!

I'm just wondering when the next moderators election is envisaged.
Anyone knows date of 2013 moderators election?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elections are only held when new moderators are needed. Since we had elections recently and do not need more/new moderators yet i do not see another election being held in the foreseeable future. That can change, of course, if this site becomes more active or current moderators become inactive.

Comment: Ok it's just logic. Thanks!